# Disable ALL wordpress updates

Tags: wordpress, updates

does this line of code disables all updates?

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

I mean, all core, minor, plugin, themes, etc.?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will disable the automatic installation of new updates but It will still check for new updates and display them.
If you're going to apply some patches you can still do it manually.

Comment: It disables the automatic installation of plugins/wp updates. It does not disable the installation.

Comment: WordPress has functions it calls "nag" functions drive you nuts if you don't upgrade.  We commented all that out.  Accepting WordPress updates over time guarantees adding new vulnerabilities into you system.  They never are known the time of the update, but found later.  When an update patches a vulnerability, the right thing to do isolate the part of the update that patches the problem, and apply that part by hand.  Accepting WP updates  have a high rate of new bugs, providing consistent stream of problems over time.